# If every borel measurable function continuous in compact metric space then metric space is finite

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space. Suppose every Borel measurable function $f : X \to \mathbf{R}$ is also continuous. Show that X is a finite set.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Now the question becomes: can our over-eager solvers restrain themselves until May1 has a chance to return and respond...

Comment: @GEdgar apparently yes.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that every measurable function is continuous. For every $x\in X$, the characteristic function $1_x:X\rightarrow R$ defined by $1_x(x)=1$ and $1_x(y)=0$ if $y\neq x$ is continuous. This implies that $1_x^{-1}((1/2,3/2))$ is an open subset. This implies that $\{x\}$ is open. Then $X$ is discrete, a compact discrete space is finite.